# PHP. Consulta a Base de datos MySQL no devuelve resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Obtengo el nombre de una Impresora ingresado por el usuario en un formulario y lo utilizo para saber su ID usando:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT IdImpresora 
                                    FROM impresoras 
                                    where modelo like '%".$busqueda."%'"); 

$IdImpresora = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Ahora trato de usar el ID de la Impresora para obtener un array con los ID de los Toner que son compatibles con esta Impresora en la tabla comp utilizando:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT IdCartucho 
                                    FROM comp
                                    WHERE IdImpresora = '%".$IdImpresora['IdImpresora']."%'");

$listID = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
    $listID[]=$row['IdCartucho'];
}
```

No obtengo ningún resultado. Esperaba obtener {3,6,7,8,10,13}

Intente obteniendo el valor entero de `$IdImpresora` antes de hacer el el query usando:

```
$IdImpresora = intval($IdImpresora['IdImpresora']);
```

posteriormente mi query quedo de esta forma:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT IdCartucho 
                                    FROM comp
                                    WHERE IdImpresora = '%".$IdImpresora['IdImpresora']."%'");
```

Aun sin resultado.

Probe este query en la consola de MySQL:

```
select IdCartucho from comp where IdImpresora = 1;
```

El resultado fue {3,6,7,8,10,13} tal como esperaba
1 es el valor que devuelve el primer query y es también el valor que paso en mi segundo query pero sin obtener resultado.
Al ejecutar el documento no obtengo ningún error.

Supongo el error esta en `$query2` pero no se que puede ser.

Necesito el array con los ID de los toner para las operaciones que haré mas adelante.

Comment: Solo quita los `%`, esos se usan solo en campos de texto y cuando la comparación es `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que busca un ID que sea string y sin embargo, es un entero. Prueba quitando las comillas del WHERE que hacen referencia al ID:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT IdCartucho 
                                    FROM comp
                                    WHERE IdImpresora = ".$IdImpresora['IdImpresora']);
```